# How can I toggle one state only and undo it when I toggle the next (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

First, I apologize for the way I phrased the question. I couldn't find a way to word it in one sentence. So, allow me to explain.

I have an API with thousands of items being looped in a v-for. The user will select one and only one at a time from the collection. And upon clicking on it will show on a separate place along with some other data (* ***so it's not a case of string interpolation. It's an object. I'm just simplifying the code in my jsfiddle to make it less confusing and run without dependencies***)

I added a boolean property to the API to toggle it true/false and a method function that does the toggle. And with the help of some v-if and v-show directives I'm hiding the other elements from rendering when they are false.

```
<div id="app">
  <div uk-grid class="card-body">
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
      <div>1. Select an Item</div>
      <div class="pods" v-for="pod in pods" :key="pod.id" :id="pod.id">
        <div class="ws-in-col" v-for="workstations in pod.workstations" :key="workstations.id" :id="workstations.id" @click="selectWS(workstations, pod)">
          <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{workstations.number}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
      <div>2. Selected Item</div>
      <div class="pods" v-for="pod in pods" :key="pod.id" :id="pod.id" v-show="pod.selected===true">
        <div class="ws-in-col" v-for="workstations in pod.workstations" :key="workstations.id" :id="workstations.id" v-show="workstations.selected===true">
          <div v-if="workstations.selected === true">
            <div class="group">
              <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{workstations.number}}</div>
              <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{workstations.text}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in the script

```
methods: {
  selectWS(workstations, pods) {
    pods.selected = !pods.selected;
    workstations.selected = !workstations.selected;
  }
}
```

However, not only it is very messy and rookie. It's buggy. The only way it works is if the user clicks on one item to show it, and clicks it again to toggle it off before clicking another one to turn it on. That's far from user-friendly.

How can I resolve this in a cleaner and professional way so that if the user clicks on 1.1, it shows 1.1 and if he wants to see 1.2, all he has to do is click on 1.2 without having to turn off 1.1 first?

Here's a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/7c4wxdnm/35/) replicating my problem

Thanks guys. Being the only Vue dev in this place is tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with IVO, instead of tracking in-item, use a value(or two) to track selection

The only reason I'm posting separate answer is that I'd recommend using a computed value *if you need to have the selected instance available as an object*.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   workstation: null,
pod: null,
pods: [
{
  id: "pod1",
  number: 1,
  selected: false,
  "workstations": [
    {
      id: "ws11",
      number: "1.1",
      text: "Some text",
      selected: false,
      close: false
    },
    {
      id: "ws12",
      number: "1.2",
      text: "Some text",
      selected: false,
      close: false
    },
    {
      id: "ws13",
      number: "1.3",
      text: "Some text",
      selected: false,
      close: false
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: "pod2",
  number: 2,
  selected: false,
  "workstations": [
    {
      id: "ws21",
      number: "2.1",
      text: "Some text",
      selected: false,
      close: false
    },
    {
      id: "ws22",
      number: "2.2",
      text: "Some text",
      selected: false,
      close: false
    },
    {
      id: "ws23",
      number: "2.3",
      text: "Some text",
      selected: false,
      close: false
    }
  ]
}
  ]
  },
  computed: {
selection(){
  if(this.workstations !== null && this.pod !== null){
    let s = this.pods.filter(p => p.id === this.pod).map(p => {
      let r = {...p}
      r.workstations = p.workstations.filter(w => w.id === this.workstation)
      return r
    })
    if (s.length === 1) return s[0]
  }
  return false
}
  },
  methods: {
   selectWS(workstations, pods) {
 if (this.pod == pods.id && this.workstation == workstations.id){
    this.pod = null;
    this.workstation = null;
  } else{
    this.pod = pods.id;
    this.workstation = workstations.id;
  }
}
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div uk-grid class="card-body">
<div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
  <div>1. Select an Item</div>
  <div class="pods" v-for="pod in pods" :key="pod.id" :id="pod.id">
    <div class="ws-in-col" v-for="workstations in pod.workstations" :key="workstations.id" :id="workstations.id" @click="selectWS(workstations, pod)">
      <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{workstations.number}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
  <div>2. Selected Item</div>
  <div v-if="selection" class="pods">
    <div class="ws-in-col">
      <div v-if="selection.workstations.length > 0">
        <div class="group">
          <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{selection.workstations[0].number}}</div>
          <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{selection.workstations[0].text}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked like a charm! I did like your idea to make the selected instance as an object since it will be manipulated further. Part of the stuff I omitted from my sample code that is inside the workstation is a bunch of switches and controls that have some code of its own. It didn't work with IVO's solution but not his fault that I omitted it. Thanks a lot for your help man

Comment: also, if the structure of your pods doesn't change, I would recommend that instead of tracking the ids in `pod` and `workstation`, you could track the indexes. then on click pass the indices (for pod you can get the index like this `v-for="(pod, p_i) in pods"` ) this will make the `selection` computed more straight forward

Answer (score 1):

You have to simply set the last selected pod/workstation and then show its properties (please run the snippet in full page otherwise you will be unable to see the right column):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selectedPod: null,
    selectedWorkstation: null,
    pods: [
    {
      id: "pod1",
      number: 1,
      selected: false,
      "workstations": [
        {
          id: "ws11",
          number: "1.1",
          text: "Some text 1",
          selected: false,
          close: false
        },
        {
          id: "ws12",
          number: "1.2",
          text: "Some text 2",
          selected: false,
          close: false
        },
        {
          id: "ws13",
          number: "1.3",
          text: "Some text 3",
          selected: false,
          close: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "pod2",
      number: 2,
      selected: false,
      "workstations": [
        {
          id: "ws21",
          number: "2.1",
          text: "Some text 4",
          selected: false,
          close: false
        },
        {
          id: "ws22",
          number: "2.2",
          text: "Some text 5",
          selected: false,
          close: false
        },
        {
          id: "ws23",
          number: "2.3",
          text: "Some text 6",
          selected: false,
          close: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  },
  methods: {
   selectWS(workstation, pod) {
      this.selectedPod = pod;
      this.selectedWorkstation = workstation;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div uk-grid class="card-body">
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
      <div>1. Select an Item</div>
      <div class="pods" v-for="pod in pods" :key="pod.id">
        <div class="ws-in-col" v-for="workstation in pod.workstations" :key="workstation.id" @click="selectWS(workstation, pod)">
          <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">
          {{workstation.number}}
          {{workstation.text}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
      <div>2. Selected Item</div>
      <div class="pods" v-if="selectedWorkstation">
        <div class="ws-in-col">
          <div>
            <div class="group">
              <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{selectedWorkstation.number}}</div>
              <div class="ws ws-number uk-text-default">{{selectedWorkstation.text}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```